# convert timestamp to hours - postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a timestamp "2161 days 21:32:40" and I want this days and hours, ONLY IN HOURS..
something like (2161*24 + 21 + 32/60 + 40/60/60) = xx.xxx hours

I cant find a nice solution.. tryed with extract and others methods with no sucess.

thanks

Comment: That's an interval, not a timestamp.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `extract (epoch)` to get the number of seconds, then divide by 3600:

```
select extract(epoch from interval '2161 days 21:32:40') / 3600.00 as hours;
```

Important note on implementation details: this counts seconds between `epoch + interval` and `epoch`. Using a different starting point could yield a different result, so if the interval you're using is the result of a difference between two timestamps, you'll be better off computing the difference in seconds between those two timestamps.

Comment: Can I use a select instead '2161 days 21:32:40'? I want something like (TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-12-10 09:19:03' , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') - TO_TIMESTAMP(X.DATE_DATATYPE)) FROM TABLE_X X

Comment: Sure... Extract epoch from the first express, extract epoch from the second one, compute the difference between the two, and divide the amount of seconds by 3600.

Comment: epoch is not acepting the return from my query (timestamp1 - timestamp2).

Comment: `select (extract(epoch from TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-12-10 09:19:03' , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) - extract(epoch from ...))) / 3600`